# 'Error' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context Multipeer Connectivity

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, multipeer-connectivity

I get this error after updating to XCode8/Swift 3

[image: 'Error' is ambiguous for type lookup]

How to fix this error?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you by chance have an `Error` class/struct in your project? In Swift 3, system class `NSError` got renamed to `Error`

Comment: Please provide text and not a screenshot so we can copy code to reproduce issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most common inside of a type that has its own `Error` type. For example:

```
class MyClass {
    enum Error {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This can also happen if you've declared an `Error` type globally. Prior to Swift 3, this was no problem, but in Swift 3 it collides with the new stdlib `Error` type. To fix it, you either need to change your `Error` type's name, or (more commonly), just be explicit about which module you're pulling from. So this line of code would become:

```
... withError error: Swift.Error?) {
```

Comment: It's weird because haven't declared any Error type. But the Swift.Error worked! Thank you

Comment: about `Error` vs. `Swift.Error?`. `Error` is a type and vague. OK. What is `Swift.Error`?

Comment: "Swift" is the name of the standard library module. So Swift.Error is the "Error" symbol found in stdlib. It's just a fully qualified symbol. You get "import Swift" implicitly in all Swift programs. So it's not vague; it's very specific. :) If the OP Cmd-clicked on "Error" in the original code, they would be taken to whatever other module is defining its own Error symbol.